# Get file with max datetime in name from directory

Tags: c#, datetime, max

I have zip files in directory. How can I get file with max datetime in file name?

My files format:

Files_2013.06.04_15-42-55.zip
Files_2013.06.03_15-42-55.zip
...

Answer (score 1):

Given that your files appear to be using a sortable format, you can just sort the names in descending lexicographic order, and take the first entry. (Or sort them in ascending order and take the last entry, of course.)

That's assuming the examples you've given are truly representative, of course. If you've got a mixture of different prefixes, for example, you would probably want to parse the date part from each filename. LINQ would make this reasonable simple:

```
var latestFile = files.OrderByDescending(ParseFileDateTime)
                      .FirstOrDefault();

...

public static DateTime ParseFileDateTime(string name)
{
    int dateTimeStartIndex = name.Length - 19;
    if (dateTimeStartIndex < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No date/time in filename: " + name);
    }
    string text = name.Substring(dateTimeStartIndex);
    return DateTime.ParseExact(text,
                               "yyyy'.'MM'.'dd'_'HH'-'mm'-'ss",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return null if `files` is an empty sequence.

Note that we're only able to get away with taking the last 19 characters because your date/time format is fixed length. If you ever changed it to use the name of the month (or something similar) you'd need to work out a different way of finding out which part of the filename was the date/time.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it:

```
//var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("path/to/dir");
var files = {"Files_2013.06.04_15-42-55.zip", "Files_2013.06.03_15-42-55.zip"};
var date = files.Max(f => 
            DateTime.ParseExact(f, "'Files_'yyyy'.'MM'.'dd'_'HH'-'mm'-'ss'.zip'", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split your string, bring the date and time together, convert it to datetime and then take a look at linq to find the max datetime.

edit: Don't forget to load all your filename into an array for exemple, do the same with your constructed datetime so you will find the good filename at the same index as the max datetime returned by linq.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with following flow:

1. Get all the file names from specific directory.
2. Parse name to get only date part (between '_' signs ). Use **Regex.Match**
3. After that you can use **DateTime.ParseExact** method to get collection of dates
4. After that you can go with linq Max() method.

Answer (score 0):

if date format same for all files and if in 2013.06.04 the *06* is a month number then you could avoid DateTime.Parse or ParseExact.

**Note: these methods applicable only if date in file name follow pattern yyyy.MM.dd_HH-mm-ss.**

For case if all file names *always* follow  same pattern (in your case 'File_yyyy.MM.dd_HH-mm-ss.zip'), then you can use max element

```
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
  var fileWithMaxDate = files.Any() ? files.Max(f=>f) : (string)null;
```

For case if only date part follow pattern yyyy.MM.dd_HH-mm-ss:

```
  private const string DatePattern = "yyyy.MM.dd_HH-mm-ss";
  private static readonly int DatePatternLen = DatePattern.Length;
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
  var fileWithMaxDate = files
                .Where
                  (f =>  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Length >= DatePatternLen)
                .OrderByDescending
                  (f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)
                            .Substring(f.Length - DatePatternLen))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

In other cases you will need to cast date part to DateTime for right ordering